# Bootstrap 3: Setting a default nav option with dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap 3 page that displays a set of tabs containing dropdowns. This looks great, but I would like to have one of the tabs be open by default when the page loads. Currently, the first tab option is set to "active", but the contents of that tab are not displayed.

How do I make the contents of a particular bootstrap dropdown choice display when the page is loaded?

Here's the code: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z3j9t/5/)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="dropdown active"> <a href="#" id="firstTab" class="dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown">First Tab <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="firstTab">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#one" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">One</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#two" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">Two</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="one">Selected Tab: One (Should be open/active by default)</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="two">Selected Tab: Two</div>
</div>
```

Comment: extend your li class to "dropdown active open"

Comment: I suppose I misstated that. I'd like the contents of the first tab to be displayed beneath the tabs. Open seems to just make the dropdown appear.

Comment: Now I got it. Give your first tab-pane "tab-pane active" instead of "tab-pane fade"

Comment: That does it! Would you mind posting this as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem just give your first tab the class "tab-pane active" instead of "tab-pane fade" and you are good to go.